# Elastic Beanstalk bash entry script won't set environment variables (Node JS)

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, environment-variables, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a script used to start my application that I also want to use to set some environment variables. This is so I can encrypt the sensitive env vars in an S3 bucket and load these before the app. Here is my script `start.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Load the S3 secrets file contents into the environment variables
eval $(aws s3 cp s3://secret-bucket-location/integration-secrets.txt - | sed 's/^/export /')

#I have also tried exporting variables here to see if my app picks them up
export TEST_ENV_VAR=testing

pm2 start server.js
```

The result is none of the environment variables are set. The ones set in the Elastic Beanstalk UI console are still set however.

It appears as though part of the EB launch config wipes them at some point.

Is there anywhere I can run this logic to allow me to set the variables? Or is there another way round this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think to pass them with `pm2 start` you'd do it like this rather than an `EXPORT`:

```
MY_VAR1=value1 MY_VAR2=value2 pm2 start server.js
```

Comment: Was fairly sure this would work when you suggested it, but I cannot seem to pass environment variables into node or pm2 using this approach. It will work for me locally, but when I run it on Elastic Beanstalk the variable will always be undefined. I am going to ask AWS to see if there is a reason for this.